# Who is kurenai?

Tags: naruto

Kurenai is not much popular character in naruto but she caught my attention during her fight with kisame and itachi. What is her background? How was she able to use gen-jutsu. Which clan she is from? Where are the other members of same clan. I can't find this information. Can some one light me up for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuhi Kurenai was born into the Yuhi clan. It was not one of the large clans. She had a relationship with Sarutobi Asuma and was pregnant with their child when he died (in Shippuuden) and she was shown with a wedding ring when telling Shikamaru about it so they were presumably married.

In Boruto she's a member of the Sarutobi clan (presumably through marriage to Asuma).

She is a genjutsu master and she was the jounin sensei of team 8 (Kiba, Hinata, Shino) in Naruto.  The manga doesn't really have much about her backstory or abilities, but the anime had all sorts of flashbacks and filler episodes.

She is revealed to be a natural chakra sensor and to have Yin release as her chakra nature, rather than an elemental aspect. She shared an appartment with Anko for a while and they are friends outside of work. She is shown to have been 9 when graduating the academy and was on the same genin team with Asuma and Raido. In the flashbacks in the anime, her father is shown to have been an active shinobi during the Kyuubi attack.

Comment: You can check out the Narutopedia for more character info: https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Kurenai_Y%C5%ABhi